# Israel as the moon which reflects the light of the sun which is HaShem?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

I can't remember the source but there was a teaching in which Israel was compared to the moon and HaShem to the sun as a metaphor in which Israel should reflect the light of HaShem. Does anyone know of such a teaching and it's source?

Answer (score 1):

You could be thinking of thr Aruch Hashulchan OC siman 426:2 :

ובפשוטו הטעם מה שמברכין על הלבנה יותר מעל כל הכוכבים, והיא קטנה כמעט מכל הכוכבים (זולת כוכב) – מפני שהיא קרובה לארץ יותר מכל הכוכבים, שאינה רחוקה מן הארץ רק בערך מ"ג אלף פרסה. ובה נראית לנו בחוש גדולתו של הקדוש ברוך הוא, בכל לילה ולילה מהילוכה המורגש, והקיפה את הארץ בכל חודש. ולכן נקראת "ירח", כדכתיב: "עשה ירח למועדים", מפני שמקפת הארץ בכל ירח ימים, ומורגש חסרונה ומילואה.

וישראל המונים ללבנה – נמשלו ללבנה: כשם שהלבנה אין לה אור מעצמותה, רק תאיר מאור השמש, כמו כן ישראל אין להם שום אור זולת אורו של הקדוש ברוך הוא, הזורח לנו באמצעות התורה הקדושה, כמו שנאמר: "שמש ומגן ד' אלקים".

וכשם שהלבנה תחשך ותאיר, כמו כן ישראל, כמו שאנו אומרים בברכתה: "וללבנה אמר שתתחדש עטרת תפארת לעמוסי בטן, שהם עתידים להתחדש כמותה". וכשם שהלבנה אף בימי חסרונה, שעל הארץ נראתה חשך – מכל מקום תאיר אל עבר פניה במרומים כידוע, כמו כן ישראל. ומכל אלו הטעמים קבלו ישראל מצוה זו בשמחה.

Middle paragraph is main part,tehillim 84:12

Answer (score 0):

http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/471045/jewish/The-Moon-and-Us.htm
Perhaps this link may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link to teaching by 
http://www.yutorah.com/lectures/lecture.cfm/843278/rabbi-robby-charnoff/bo-3-the-nation-of-israel-a-reflection-of-the-moon/
Speaker Rabbi Robby Charnoff:
Description
The first mitzvah given to Israel as a nation is "hachodesh hazeh lachem," the sanctification of the months beginning with Nissan at the Exodus. What is the connection between the birth of Israel as a nation and this first mitzvah? Why is it important that Israel live in a dimension of time defined by the moon? (Part of HaMidrasha at QC, OU-JLIC's Torah learning program for women at Queens College.)
He references Ruth 4 list of generations 1-15 each surpassing the previous generation until Solomon, followed by 15 generations of decline to galut. He notes this matches the phase of the moon. Great Shira.